# How to Add Event Handler (Or Similar Function) to Nested Private Object

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on a project in VB.Net that uses a variety of dynamically created panels, that have dynamically created form elements, that dynamically resize as the screen is resized.  To help this not take up thousands of lines of repeated code for all of the similar elements I created the following setup:

```
Public Class PanelComponents

    Dim componentsList As New List(Of PanelComponent)
    'Methods etc here

    Private MustInherit Class PanelComponent
        'Method data here
    End Class

    Private Class ComboBoxComponent
        Inherits PanelComponent
        'Method data here
    End Class

    'More Children of PanelComponent

End Class
```

For the most part this has been working out brilliantly for me for the execution of my program, however I have currently hit a snag.  On the part of the program I am working on right now, I want to be able to add an event to one of the `ComboBoxComponent` objects while outside of the `PanelComponents` class.  I want to make it so that when the user changes the selected index of the combo box, it triggers a method, which modifies some of the codes variables based upon the change in selection.

However because my `ComboBoxComponent` is a private class nested within my `PanelComponents` class I am not sure how to add an event handler to or (or how to reference it for a `Handles` call).

Comment: Define an event in your panel. Handle event of the combo boxes and in the handler, raise event of panel. Then outside of panel subscribe to event of panel.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Could you elaborate a little bit please?

Comment: I had a comment but deleted it. I just realized that everything is private, and I am confused. How is this actually used?

Comment: @djv To use this, every time I am trying to add new components to the screen, I call an `AddComponent` method which adds a new component (of a specified type) to the `componentsList`.  Up until now, every component has needed the same type of methods (resize, adjust padding, etc.) so this was working for me fine.  However I feel my design of this may actually be my problem here and I may need to rebuild this :\

Comment: @djv To expand a bit, the reason I made my own `PanelComponent` class was because each TextBox, or ComboBox, or whatever I needed, needed to have a Label accompanying it.  So I figured I'd just essentially wrap the two of them together as a single object and save myself some annoyance.

Comment: The ComboBoxComponent isn't even a `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` at all. So did you design it from scratch (except for the Label accompanying it)? Wouldn't it make more sense to have a class derive from ComboBox, then add a Label to it, so you still have all the `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` functionality?

Comment: @djv When I initially programmed this, I wasn't sure how exactly to add a Label to an Object Inheriting `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`.  Hell part of me is still a little confused.  Let's say I make a class called `CB_Custom` that Inherits from ComboBox.  If I add a Label Object to that class, when I add an Instance of the class, where would the Label show up?

Comment: @djv Based on the comments, is seems it's a panel, containing a label and a combo box. And the OP wants to expose change event of the combo to outside of the panel.

Comment: @RezaAghaei `Private Class ComboBoxComponent Inherits PanelComponent`

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't make any change in the solution. Whenever you want to expose the event of a child object to outside of its parent OP should follow the approach which I describes.

Comment: @RezaAghaei out of curiosity, could you use the same classes and access modifiers as OP, and reformulate your answer? It's hard to see how it answers the question in its current state.

Comment: @djv I'm not going to do that. The answer is quite clear :) The main part of the answer is the single paragraph of the post. The rest, is an *Example* showing how to expose an event of child control to outside of the parent in *any* context.